# Users that can add other users in drupal 7

Tags: 7, users

Scenario is as follows: admin adds users (coordinators). Coordinators should be able to add another type of users (editors) which can create content. What is the best solution to this scenario? I don't want any of the users assign roles to other users. Coordinator should be able to add only one, defined type of user.

Answer (score 1):

There's a module for that: [Administer Users by Role](http://drupal.org/project/administerusersbyrole).

> This module allows site builders to set up fine-grained permissions for allowing users to edit and delete other users — more specific than Drupal Core's all-or-nothing 'administer users' permission. It also provides and enforces a 'create users' permission.
>
> To use this module:
>
> 1. Create a role for the users who you'd like to be able to create/edit/delete other users
> 2. Give that new role the 'administer users' permission and give it the desired *Administer Users by Role* permissions

I'm using it exactly for the same purpose you described.

Comment: I followed your suggestion, but how to automatically set the role for the users created by coordinators?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I use [Role Assign](http://drupal.org/project/roleassign) to configure what roles can be assigned to created users. Not automatic though.